# How to Integrate Facebook iOS 3.5.3 SDK embedded Webview in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

Hi I am new to **iOS** and developing app with **Facebook ios 3.5.3 SDK**.
How to integrate the iOS **EmbeddedWebview** mechanism in app with **lasted 3.5.3 facbook sdk**.

With **embedded web view** how to implemente the below logics

```
1.Login
2.Logout
3.Permissions -basic info, email, birthday,friendlist ,ect.,
4.App did become active method- applicationDidBecomeActive:
5.app will terminate method -applicationWillTerminate:
6.FBSession maintenance.
```

am sure **asking for lasted iOS facebook 3.5.3 SDK** only...

If have any ideas please share your ideas , I hope its will help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed document provided by Facebook dev. Please refer it first of your self and try it.

```
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/
```

After that if you get any trouble let me know.

Comment: I got some idea , let me try and tell .

Comment: Sure easy to do, I hope you can easily do it.